# Heading arrow always sitting right side along with the title

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to keep the right side arrow always right of the title, but in some scenarios only the arrow comes down. (If you move the fiddle preview handle you may see). Following is the HTML structure and the css are used.

```
<div class="headline">
  <h3>
    <a href="#">Bowie comeback reaches number six<span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span></a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.headline {
    padding: 15px 12px 12px;
}
h3 {font-size:30px;}
.arrow{
    background: transparent url(http://blog.sameerast.com/wp-content/themes/elements-of-seo_1.4/images/bullet.gif) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9Mst7/

Do I have another approach or best to win this?

**UPDATE**: when title comes to second line, then also arrow should be sitting be side.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is putting the arrow as a right positioned `background-image` to the `h3`. It will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Mst7/2/

Comment: @Sunyatasattva I think this solution works fine for one line title, but when title comes to 2nd line, it doesnt follow.

Comment: Well, depends on what you mean by doesn't follow. It stays in the center. Which I understand it is not exactly what you want, and that's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer. To just give you a pointer in a direction you might not have considered yet.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the span and add the arrow icon as a background image on the anchor `<a>`.

HTML:

```
<div class="headline">
  <h3>
    <a href="#" class="arrow">Bowie comeback reaches number six ddd</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

css:

```
.headline {
    padding: 15px 12px 12px;
}
h3 {font-size:30px;}
.arrow{
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: transparent url(http://blog.sameerast.com/wp-content/themes/elements-of-seo_1.4/images/bullet.gif) right center no-repeat;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6R6Ar/2/

Comment: I think this solution works fine for one line title, but when title comes to 2nd line, it doesnt follow.

Comment: Blasted IE.  I created another solution but it's not very pretty.  I wrapped the last word with the span.arrow.  Now when it wraps the arrow follows the last word.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6R6Ar/3/